# unity 2017.4.15 crashing on export package

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two unity versions(2017.4 and 2018.3.6) on mac book pro late 2013. both of unity crashes when i try to export package from any of the version.
A window appears which shows a long report copied below. how i can get rid from this

Process:               Unity [591]
Path:                  /Applications/Unity 2017.4/Unity 2017.4.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
Identifier:            com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x
Version:               Unity version 2017.4.15f1 (2017.4.15f1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Unity [591]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-03-04 08:56:21.246 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.3 (18D109)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        CCFE4D87-8DFF-C67A-810F-F0C09D34F3EB

Time Awake Since Boot: 620 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        82  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos.overcommit

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'NSRunAlertPanel may only be invoked from the main thread. Behavior on other threads is undefined.'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: If you have an antivirus program, does it still do it if thats briefly turned off?

Comment: Do you use Unity Hub?

Comment: BugFinder i have no antivirus     caxapexac i didnot use unity hub